# How to re-use a calculated value in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose I have the following D3 code:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g").data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("width", function(d) {return calculateValue(d)+1})
    .attr("height", function(d) {return calculateValue(d)*2});
```

And let's suppose that the calculateValue() function is somewhat expensive. What is the best way to pre-calculate the value for each item in the data?

I have done something like this to pre-calculate the values:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g").data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .each(function(d) {d._preCalculated = calculateValue(d)})
    .attr("width", function(d) {return d._preCalculated+1})
    .attr("height", function(d) {return d._preCalculated*2});
```

But I don't like this approach because I don't want to mutate the data. I would rather use some external context or scope to accomplish this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Could you not both calculate and assign it in the each function?

```
 ...
 .each(function(d) {
     var bigCalc = calculateValue(d);
     d3.select(this)
        .attr("width", bigCalc+1)
        .attr("height", bigCalc*2)
    ;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the data in a variable with global scope, you can set up a global array as an index for the data.

```
  var precalc = [];

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g").data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .each(function(d,i) { precalc[i] = calculateValue(d)})
    .attr("width", function(d,i) {return precalc[i]+1})
    .attr("height", function(d,i) {return precalc[i]*2});
```

If it's the sort of thing you're worried might get run multiple times (say, if you refresh the graph in some way), you could also do a quick check to see if it was already cached:

```
    .each(function(d,i) { if(typeof precalc[i]!="undefined") precalc[i] = calculateValue(d); })
```

Though if it were me, I would probably just mutate the data the way you did before — it saves worrying about whether indices move around or whether you've declared the object correctly or whatever.